# How can I get this batch process to use user inputs properly?

Tags: batch-file, command-line-interface, network-drive

We use a bunch of remote drives at my workplace and I'm developing a catch-all drive mapper .bat file to help people who are less technical map the drives.

I currently have one running this code:

```
@net use G: \\u-dom1.u-ssi.net\DFSRoot05784 /persistent:yes
@pause
```

That successfully maps the DFSRoot05784 drive to the G: letter.

What I'm trying to do is allow users to provide a drive letter and mapping address, which the code then uses to perform the same action. Currently I've come up with this:

```
@ Echo Create new drive mapping

set /p driveLetter= "Choose a drive letter"

set /p driveAddress= "Enter a drive address"

@net use driveLetter: driveAddress /persistent:yes

@pause
```

It successfully asks for a drive letter and mapping address, but I get an error 67 afterwards. Is there something I'm not understanding about how the command line accepts and uses variables? What do I need to change to get it to work how I need it to?

Comment: I would suggest that you do not just accept that the end user has input an actual drive letter, or even if they had, that their selection is actually available for use. Either provide them with a list of available letters, or unavailable letters to guide them; or verify their input and its availability in the background, before mapping it.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the variables in `%` to have the system identify them as variables and not plain text:

I also suggest you first verify the drive letter is not already in use.

```
@echo off
:begin
echo( & echo Create new drive mapping & echo(
set /p "driveLetter=Choose a drive letter: "
if not exist %driveletter%: (
    set /p "driveAddress=Enter a drive address: "
   ) else (
   echo drive "%driveletter%:" already in use please try again.
   goto begin
 )
   net use %driveLetter%: %driveAddress% /persistent:yes

pause
```

Also, this assumes that the user actually type the full address. i.e `\\server\path` which will then be stored in the variable `%driveAddress%`